# Entity Framework with SQL Server - massive performance difference on different environments

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2014

I have a issue with a query when running on local environment with a exact copy of the test database pulling 150,000 rows takes around 15-20 seconds when running on our test server pulling only 15,000 it takes ages 10 minutes and counting.

I suspect that my development machine has more ram and a faster processor but I have reduced the `Take()` to 10% of what it is on my machine and it still takes ages. The test database is a secondary test server that is rarely used for anything so I doubt this bottle neck is other traffic or locks but I have not conclusively proved this yet.

oo to clarify I have tried running this query from debug on my machine pointing at our test database and also deployed it the test server and run it directly on the box both are extremely slow.

Other differences may be worth knowing our test server uses SQL Server 2014 Standard edition, on my development machine I'm using SQL Server 2014 Developers edition.

```
var effectedSegmentDataRows = (from camp in ourContext.CampaignMails
                                            .Where(x =>
                                            x.CreatedAt > startDate &&
                                            x.CreatedAt < todaysDate)
                                            .Distinct()
                                            .Where(f => f.SegmentDatas.Any() == false)

                                            .OrderByDescending(f => f.CreatedAt)
                                           .Skip(current).Take(takeAmount)
                               join mc in ourContext.MainCompanies on camp.LeadId equals mc.LeadId
                               join sd in ourContext.SegmentDatas on mc.Id equals sd.MainCompanyId
                               where
                                   ((camp.Postcode == sd.MainCompany.MainTradingPostcode && sd.AddressTypeId == addressTypeCompany) ||
                                    (camp.Postcode == sd.Officer.Postcode && sd.AddressTypeId == addressTypeResidential)) 
                               select new
                               {
                                   camp = new
                                   {
                                       camp.Id,
                                       camp.TradingName,
                                       camp.Address1,
                                       camp.Postcode,
                                       camp.CreatedAt,
                                       camp.FirstName,
                                       camp.LastName

                                   },
                                   sd,
                                   Officer = new
                                   {
                                       sd.Officer.AddressLine1,
                                       sd.Officer.Postcode,
                                       sd.Officer.Forename,
                                       sd.Officer.Surname

                                   },
                                   MainCompany = new
                                   {
                                       sd.MainCompany.Name,
                                       sd.MainCompany.MainTradingAddressLine1,
                                       sd.MainCompany.MainTradingPostcode
                                   }
                               }
    ).OrderByDescending(f => f.camp.CreatedAt).ToList();
```

The database on test server and on my development machine are both copies of our live environment and identical +/- a few test rows i may of added on my development box

Any ideas are greatly appreciated

Comment: run the query directly without EF and see. Also make sure you have the same index on the server as local

Comment: It could be many things but do not get hung up on the fact that its EF. Take the generated query and run it in both environments, compare the actual execution plans, compare the reads, etc. This could be anything, fragmented indexes, high torn page count, etc.

Comment: how long does it take to open a connection? how long does it take to verify your model in your DbContext? how long does it take to actually execute the query? this might help to close up on the problem, however I do not think you'll find much help in this remote environment.

Comment: I believe this boils down to cache and tempdb as after i reset my sql service and cleared the temp db the time it took on development machine increased dramatically. as i was working a lot with these tables i believe my development machine must of cached and stored the majority of this query only conclusion i come to that makes sense